# Why isn't ${#array[@]:-} valid in bash 4.4, when it was accepted by earlier releases?

Tags: bash

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
declare -a arr=()
echo ${#arr[@]:-}
```

Fails on Arch Linux (bash 4.4.5):

```
-bash: ${#arr[@]:-}: bad substitution
```

While it works on Ubuntu 14.04 (bash 4.3.11) or Debian 8 (4.3.30).

Comment: This substitution... doesn't actually make *sense*. Why would you expect it to work at all? (And being clear -- if something isn't documented to work, then it ceasing to work in the future isn't a bug, but just a change in undefined behavior).

Comment: (An array length can't ever be empty or null, so "default to empty" makes no sense).

Comment: The other thing is that the git repository for bash doesn't actually have changeset-level granularity -- Chet just does a new commit every time he publishes a new release, so there isn't enough information to bisect down to "change X, made with commit message Y in response to bug Z, caused this delta in behavior".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `valid_array_reference` function in `arrayfunc.c`, the following check was added:

```
if (t[len+1] != '\0')
  return 0;
```

Thus, the expansion is now validated to end at the expected point, whereas previously, invalid/unexpected content following the subscript was ignored.

---

This is documented in the CWRU/changelog entry for 6/5 as follows:

> `arrayfunc.c`
>
> - `valid_array_reference`: make sure the array reference is properly
>     terminated after the first subscript; return invalid if there is
>     anything following the closing `]`

Notably, `valid_array_reference` is called from `subst.c` in `valid_length_expression` -- which is called as a precursor to `parameter_brace_expand_length`, which actually performs the substitution at hand.